# Button on subview untouchable after add to view program

Tags: swift, addsubview

I try to add a subview to a view, but after added, the button on subview is untouchable. I have check the status of button, user interaction is enable. and after add subview, the UI of subview are show up correctly.

The subview class:

```
class ErrorInfoView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
var callback: (()->())?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {

    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ErrorInfoView", owner: self, options: nil)
    containerView.frame = self.bounds
    containerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    addSubview(containerView)
}

func configure(message: String, callback: @escaping ()->()) {
    self.messageLabel.text = message
    self.callback = callback
}

@IBAction func pressRetryButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.callback?()
}
```

}

The parent view:

```
            let errorView = ErrorInfoView(frame: self.tableViewContainer.frame)

        errorView.configure(message: error) {
            // do something, but not be called
        }
        self.tableViewContainer.addSubview(errorView)
        self.tableViewContainer.bringSubviewToFront(errorView)

        errorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = errorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableViewContainer.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = errorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableViewContainer.centerYAnchor)

        self.tableViewContainer.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Did you connect the `pressRetryButton` action in your xib file?

Comment: yes, I have. And If I use storyboard and set up a view as ErrorInfoView, pressRetryButton can be called.

Comment: What happens if you retain the return value from `loadNibNamed`? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1618147-loadnibnamed) explicitly says to retain the return value.